# GN: How to assign a random range of colors to islands?

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

The **Mesh Island** node is helpful for isolating the geometry islands:

[image]

But I'm only getting binary black and white values:

[image]

How can I map this across a *float* range of `0.0` to `1.0`?

(Then I could color it using a **ColorRamp**.)

Comment: Simply use float in the random value node?

Answer (score 3):

Fractions or decimals are not integers. To get a value in between, switch the Random Value node type to to *Float* or try any other type.

Comment: D'oh! So obvious! Actually, I had tried that and it didn't make any difference. Can you guess why? ...The Group Output node's Output Attribute socket was still dark green, expecting an integer type. After creating a new (float value) output, it works. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Mentalist I guess a could never have figured that out :D

Comment: @Mentalist if your output is an integer, all values passed to it will be cast (converted) to an integer, which for floats means truncating the fraction (flooring positive values and ceiling negative values). You can modify domains, types, names of inputs/outputs in the Numbers Panel of the tree editor

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you for those details. I was wondering about whether it would *round* to an integer, but it's helpful to know it will *truncate*.